# How to access all repeated structured properties in GAE ndb Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
class X(ndb.Model): 
    content = ndb.StringProperty() 
    number = ndb.IntegerProperty() 

class P(ndb.Model): 
    unit = ndb.StructuredProperty(X, repeated=True)
```

Using Datastore viewer, i could see the following stored data:

```
Entity Kind             P 
Entity Key              ag1kZXZ-bGlmZXN3YWxschoLEg1BZHZlcnRpc2VtZW50IGCAgICA4NcKDA 
ID                      6015428115566296 
unit.content (list)     [u'Apple', u'Coca Cola', u'Orange', u'Audi']
unit.number (list)      [10L, 5L, 10L, 10L]
```

Goal: To access the different unit.content values (like, 'Apple', etc)

[i am a novice in GAE Python; so please excuse if the question is too silly]

My (unsuccessful)attempt[i tried a few other ways but in vain]:

```
unitv_query = P.query() 
mv = unitv_query.fetch() 
    for a in mv.unit: 
        logging.info ("content=[%s]", a.content)
```

I get the following error:

```
    :: 
    File "C:\learn\eg5.py", line 495, in render_unit

        for a in mv.unit:

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'unit'
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unit` property will be a list of `X's` however you are looping over the wrong things
You could should be,

```
unitv_query = P.query() 
mv = unitv_query.fetch() 
    # mv is a list of P
    for a in mv: 

        # now loop over each entity in unit property.
        for i in a.unit:

            logging.info ("content=[%s]", i.content)
```

In your code you are trying to access unit from `mv` however mv is a list of `P` entities - the result of the query and therefore you can't access `unit`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i have one more doubt:
How to query for all such items('content') for which the value of 'number' is greater than 2

Comment: Have you read the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties and tried such a query.  I can't give you an example as I don't have any repeated StructuredProperty to test.